# Standardize all timestamps with multiple timezones in a Spark DataFrame to UTC format

Tags: python, pyspark

I am using pyspark with the purpose of standardizing a column of type string that contains timestamps in different formats, and different time zones, for instance:

```
| Timestamp                 |
|---------------------------|
| 2017-01-01T00:00:00+01:00 |
| 2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z  |
| 2017-01-01T00:00:00+02:00 |
```

I have then created the following transformation to standardize these timestamps to their corresponding UTC format:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

def _standardized_timestamp_column(column_name: str):
   return f.when(
       f.col(column_name).endswith('Z'),
       f.to_utc_timestamp(f.regexp_replace(f.col(column_name), '\Z', ''), 'UTC')
   ).when(
       f.col(column_name).contains('+'),
       f.to_utc_timestamp(f.split(f.col(column_name), '\+')[0], f.split(f.col(column_name), '\+')[1])
   )

my_df = my_df.withColumn('UTC', _standardized_timestamp_column('Timestamp'))
```

Unfortunately, this function is not converting the timestamps as expected

```
+-------------------------+-------------------+
|Timestamp                |UTC                |  # Expected
+-------------------------+-------------------+
|2017-01-01T00:00:00+01:00|2017-01-01 00:00:00|  # 2016-12-31 23:00:00
|2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z |2020-01-01 01:00:00|  # 2020-01-01 00:00:00
|2017-01-01T00:00:00+02:00|2017-01-01 00:00:00|  # 2016-12-31 22:00:00
+-------------------------+-------------------+
```

Am I misusing this function?

Comment: The to_utc_timestamp(utc, 'Asia/Kolkata') works like this , (timestamp_column, the _timezone_this_column_it_belongs_to) , Also, it is expected to Give the stranded timezone what this functions understands such as :   Asia/Kolkata etc

Comment: @dsk from the pyspark documentation: tz: A string detailing the time zone ID that the input should be adjusted to. It should be in the format of either region-based zone IDs or zone offsets.https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=join#pyspark.sql.functions.to_utc_timestamp

Comment: hmm... Apparently yes, I had such problem once and while providing the correct timezone it worked..

Comment: @dsk the fact is I am not using pyspark 3.0.0 and in 2.4.2 tz still has to be the correct timezone name as you suggested. I need to be more careful about which version of the docs I am reading.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that providing the timezone offset directly to the `to_utc_timestamp` function was added in latest versions of Spark (3.0.0+).

In my current version, 2.4.2, I need to provide either a timezone in Region/City name, such as `Europe/Rome`, or a timezone offset, like `GMT+01`.

I adjusted my function a little and now I am getting the expected values:

```
def standardized_timestamp_column(column_name: str):

    hours = f.split(f.split(f.col(column_name), '\+')[1], ':')[0]

    return f.when(
        f.col(column_name).endswith('Z'),
        f.to_utc_timestamp(f.split(f.col(column_name), '\.')[0], 'UTC')
    ).when(
        f.col(column_name).contains('+'),
        f.to_utc_timestamp(f.split(f.col(column_name), '\+')[0],
                           f.when(hours == '00', 'UTC').otherwise(f.concat(f.lit('GMT+'), hours)))
    )
```

I acknowledge it's not the best solution, any improvement is highly appreciated